# android studio firebase realtime database store data using volly lib or okhttps

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-volley, okhttp

i was tryjing to store data on my firebase realtime database using volly lib and okhttps. but i failled.. is there any way to store data on firebase realtime database without using the sdk on android studio..

i am trying this code

```
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                .add("message", "Your message")
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://jukes-86dd2-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/Bangla/json")
                .put(formBody) // PUT here.
                .build();

        try {
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

            // Do something with the response.
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: To access the REST API of the Firebase Database, the URL needs to end in `.json`. You have `/json` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I hope before making direct calls to firebase database, You had authenticate your request with access token. [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth)

If authentication is already then and then you can make call firebase database to perform various operations.

Let's assume you had already completed authorization part. Then you should have to use collection name with `.json` instead of `/json`

You can do it by referring below code.

So your URL should be,

```
https://jukes-86dd2-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/{collection_name}.json
```

Instead of,

```
https://jukes-86dd2-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/{collection_name}/json
```

```
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                .add("message", "Your message")
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://jukes-86dd2-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/Bangla.json")
                .put(formBody) // PUT here.
                .build();

        try {
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

            // Do something with the response.
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

For more supported operations, refer [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database#section-post).

**Note:**
But as an Android developer, I would prefer to use firebase database SDK to perform database operation instead of storing my access-token with code.

Comment: Tried But not working app keeps stoping

Comment: @AbuHanif Can you please share the error log?

Comment: ---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (22073) for package com.hanif.tikfollow ----------------------------
--------- beginning of crash
--------- beginning of system
--------- beginning of main
---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (22073) for package com.hanif.tikfollow ----------------------------
---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (22576) for package com.hanif.tikfollow ----------------------------